# how to print string variable in python

Tags: python

```
name = input("What is your name: ")
age = int(input("How old are you: "))
year = str((2014 - age)+100)
print(name + " will be 100 years old in the year " + year)
```

I am trying this code in python, but it is not executing, what corrections needs to be done?

Comment: Why do you have `*` at the end of your last line?

Comment: And why a `*` at the beginning of line 1?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code other than the asterisks at the start and end...

Comment: From your script, removed special character * and check your machine has python, also check python version. print method different in python 2 and 3

Comment: and also change year to current :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From your question**

```
name = input("What is your name: ")
age = int(input("How old are you: "))
year = str((2014 - age)+100)
print(name + " will be 100 years old in the year " + year)
```

Your code is just fine, change your input to raw_input for name variable.

**NOTE**: raw_input returns a string, input tries to run as Python expression.